# Why do I get a runtime error when using matcher.match from OpenCV in a Unity dll?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I am using OpenCV to get back data from frame from a Unity application. 
i made a dll which works fine for most of the things but when I want to study the match between two frames I get a running time error.

I used the code bellow :

In c++ using OpenCV library :

```
int* Correction3DMasks(Color32* raw, int width, int height, Color32* VirtualCamRaw, int VirtualCamwidth, int VirtualCamheight, int minimalLength, int MaxiLineGap)
{    
      int minHessian = 20;

  FastFeatureDetector  detector( minHessian );

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;


    RealCamFeed = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, raw);
    VirtualCamFeed = Mat(VirtualCamheight, VirtualCamwidth, CV_8UC4, VirtualCamRaw);



    Canny(RealCamFeed, RealCamFeed, 200, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(RealCamFeed, RealCdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

    Canny(VirtualCamFeed, VirtualCamFeed, 200, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(VirtualCamFeed, VirtualCdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

  //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector

  detector.detect( RealCamFeed, keypoints_1 );
  detector.detect( VirtualCamFeed, keypoints_2 );

  //-- Draw keypoints
  Mat img_keypoints_1; Mat img_keypoints_2;

  cv::drawKeypoints( RealCamFeed, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
  drawKeypoints( VirtualCamFeed, keypoints_2, img_keypoints_2, Scalar::all(-1), DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );

  //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
  imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
  imshow("Keypoints 2", img_keypoints_2 );

       //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
     SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

          Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

  extractor.compute( RealCamFeed, keypoints_1, descriptors_object );
  extractor.compute( VirtualCamFeed, keypoints_2, descriptors_scene );

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
   FlannBasedMatcher matcher (new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2));
  std::vector< DMatch > matches;

  matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);




  //-- Localize the object
  std::vector<Point2f> obj;
  std::vector<Point2f> scene;

  for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
  {
    //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
    obj.push_back( keypoints_1[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    scene.push_back( keypoints_2[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  } 

  if(matches.size() > 0)
  Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

   //deal with H to put it in res

       return res; 
}
```

This function is simply called from Unity with the render texture from two camera with a close position from each other.
I tried debug the thing and it seems that the lines `matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);` is the cause for the error.

The error is :

> Microsoft Visual c++ Runtime Library
>
> Runtime Error!
>
> Program:
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

I hope I am clear enough.
Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: I add that the "imshow" instructions run and display keypoints.